# Как делегировать данный запрос?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как делегировать данные условия без кликов?

```
     if ($("#check_mtrx_a").prop("checked")){
    if ($('.matrix_a tr:first td').length >= 10){
      $('.add_col').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
  }
  if ($("#check_mtrx_b").prop("checked")){
    if ($('.matrix_b tr:first td').length === 10){
      $('.add_col').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function DisableAddColumn() {
  if ($("#check_mtrx_a").prop("checked")){
    if ($('.matrix_a tr:first td').length >= 10){
      $('.add_col').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
  if ($("#check_mtrx_b").prop("checked")){
    if ($('.matrix_b tr:first td').length === 10){
      $('.add_col').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  DisableAddColumn();
});
```

Comment: Не срабатывает.Пока получилось только при one(click) запустить

Comment: @Drop Все срабатывает. Вы хотели без кликов - ни одного клика в моем коде нет.

Comment: Про клик не слова не могу сказать.Но вот далее мои условия уже не хотят работать при добавлении новых элементов на странице.

Comment: @Drop - поработайте, пожалуйста, над формулированием Вашего вопроса

Comment: Ну главное суть понял.Спасибо